# Correctly declare interface or type for functions params

Tags: typescript, types, interface

How to correctly declare type for param **cardsByStatus** inside function **addCardsToStatus**? It works for *cardsByStatus: any*, but it doesn't make sense for me.

*Error: Property 'map' does not exist on type '{ cards: number[]; }'*

[Link for live example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAEsCGAbALgCwAqPiAys+yYAzlAN4BQUVUAkiOgE4D2A5g8ESQLxQDkdjVu068ANJWoBhJhAAOiYMmAATKD17S5CpcrHkAvuWQBPWcFqT4DZUQBCxvAWJqyEqgG0i+QiQCWIWAQUDCxcb2IAXQAuCmo4qABjKxsoqHAIACNgBncItyhDQ38lBgAzeATzGgB5WWRfJhASWOomOoamxx9UrwZ-FgNyclKwEAT6xqh4ZWVLayIAFSYu4gAKJPn7FaJUmjmbLfCiUSg2iabd2vOiAEpXOITGrzIzjqJt-Uv2p5dXp6GHsk7A4ju4-p0jhEAHQQeCyVbrZJRdJZBh3LgAPkSyRu+Q2BxBTiI7gARAJmGwOEQSdDYfDEdZkZBUeisfjcYNyI8mshsZtCT4XKRaPQKcIdmQ+SkoLkCidNPJFCpUsL8RL3FAAIwnABMJwAzFAIgUClynrzwdxJZbtql+KKhFTeKbyNNZkCltsGQTtidLTcgA)

```
enum HealthPlanStatus {
    InProgress = 'InProgress',
    Completed = 'Completed',
}
type ICardsByStatus = {
    [status in HealthPlanStatus]:{
        cards: number[]
    }
}
interface IOptions {
    optionsStatus: string
}

function addCardsToStatus(cardsByStatus: ICardsByStatus, options: IOptions) {
    const {optionsStatus}: IOptions = options

    cardsByStatus[optionsStatus].map((card:number) => card)
    cardsByStatus["InProgress"].map((card:number) => card)

}

const cardsByStatus = { InProgress: { cards: [] }, Completed: { cards: [ 1, 2, 3 ] } }
const options = { optionsStatus: 'InProgress' }

addCardsToStatus(cardsByStatus, options)
```

Comment: `cardsByStatus["InProgress"]` is an object therefore you cannot `map()`. Use `cardsByStatus["InProgress"].cards.map((card:number) => card)` to loop over the cards. Additionally of you to use `IOptions` to access the objects as a key you should use `optionsStatus: HealthPlanStatus` as a type otherwise the key might not exist on the given object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first change the interface `IOptions`:

```
interface IOptions {
    optionsStatus: HealthPlanStatus
}
```

If `optionsStatus` is defined as `string`, it is not allowed to use it to index on object of type `ICardsByStatus`.

You also defined `ICardByStatus` to have an additional key `{ cards: number[] }`. To access the array, you should use this key.

```
cardsByStatus[optionsStatus].cards.map((card:number) => card)
cardsByStatus["InProgress"].cards.map((card:number) => card)
```

And lastly TypeScript will now complain if you pass `options` to the method if you defined it as an object with a `string` inside. So we should change it to this:

```
const options = { optionsStatus: HealthPlanStatus.InProgress }

addCardsToStatus(cardsByStatus, options)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=25&ssc=41&pln=23&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAEsCGAbALgCwAqPiAys%20yYAzlAN4BQUVUAkiOgE4D2A5g8ESQLxQDkdjVu068ANJWoBhJhAAOiYMmAATKD17S5CpcrHkAvuWQBPWcFqT4DZUQBCxvAWJqyEqgG0i%20QiQCWIWAQUDCxcb2IAXQAuCmo4qABjKxsoqHAIACNgBncItyhDQ38lBgAzeATzGgB5WWRfJhASWOomOoamxx9UuCQ0TGwu4gNyclKwEAT6xqh4ZWVLayIAFSYhogAKJKX7ddSaRZtd8KJRKDbppv3ay6IASlc4hMavMguOonX9a-aXl3eXqMnsk7A4Tu4AZ0ThEAHTbGwwiDwWQbLbJKLpLIMB5cAB8iWSd3y8NB63cACIBMw2BwiOTYSTEcjUfCMZAsTj8fCiSNyM8msgCTswU5uGRaPRqcIiKlSEKUlBcgUzpp5IoVLL5TLFVAAIxnABMZwAzFAIgUCnyXoLIWK5ba9oE%20iFBicYVShLTLeQ5gsQat1mjheszra7kA)